# Old movie on a spaceship with an evil scientist with robots

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

I am trying to find old movie that I saw as a kid. Now I am not even sure if that one scene that I remember is accurate in my memory. But here is what I remember:

- it happened on spaceship
- there was some evil scientist with robots
- one of the good guys was killed by the robot with some blades/drills or something like that (the scientist commanded the robot to do it)

Now I found similar scene in *The Black Hole* 1979, but I am sure it’s not it because there were no people, maybe just +1 except the scientist and the victim, and also the whole killing scene was longer and you could actually saw the blades/drills entering the body and killing that man.

Comment: When were you a kid?

Comment: Iam not remember how old I was in that time :-D But lets say I think it cannot be newer than 1995. So certainly 1995 and older

Comment: I know you say it's not the match, but you're describing The Black Hole pretty closely. I've found that a lot of the scenes I "remember" watching from when I was very young were heavily edited in my memory to be much more graphic than they actually were.

Comment: Sounds like the situation the main characters / extras are facing in one of the early chapters of the book Redshirts by John Scalzi.  Given that much of the book was a spoof of sci-fi shows such as Star Trek, does anyone know if Scalzi has commented on what his inspiration for the killer robots was?  (The description sounds gory enough that it would not have been shown as part of a Star Trek episode.)

Comment: @moopet right I know but I really remember it differently. The sets were more bright maybe even white and you could really saw that guy be pierced. I believe this part is not my mind imagination over the years

Comment: This might also be a distorted memory of _[Forbidden Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet)_ (1956).

Comment: @Spencer I think I never saw this one

Comment: Reminiscent of [Saturn 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_3)

Comment: @James McLeod Never saw that one either but quick look on that tells me this isnt it. I will try to search for it more. I would definitely recognize it but but no luck with trying on google with any possible combination of "robot kills" :-D

Comment: @TomParis it’s pretty obscure and quite bad, so it was a long shot.

Comment: Slightly reminiscent of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(film). However, the robots in Android look human, and in the killing scene the "blades/drills" (actually a disembodied robot arm with very pointy "fingers") end up stuck in a wall. The robot then just lifts up its victim and snaps his neck.

Answer (score 2):

My immediate trigger: Movie *[Saturn 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_3)* (1980): Kirk Douglas, Farrah Fawcett and Harvey Keitel on deep space (Saturn) space station.

> Trapped in the control room, both Alex and Adam are surprised to see Benson's face on their monitor. The two are directed by a voice they recognize as Benson's to leave the control room, both surprised that Benson is even alive. To their shock, the two are confronted by Hector, now wearing Benson's head.

Comment: OP ruled this out in a comment 10 hours before you posted this answer.

Comment: Still, not a bad match, and partial or wrong answers that still match are worthy answers.